# accurate and reliable Base36 in PHP?

Tags: php

Here is my code so far:

```
function base36($value, $return_size)
{
    $base36 = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $buffer = str_pad("", $return_size);
    $offset = $return_size;

    do {
        $buffer[--$offset] = $base36[$value % 36];
    } while ($value /= 36);

    return $buffer;
}
```

`$value: 64bit integer`
`$return_size: the expected size in bytes the function should return`

It doesn't work correctly, **because the $value is 64bit integer** and because PHP forces double divisions. PHP seems pretty limited when it's about 64bit integers. How to make the above code work like the **exact C version would?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Native:

[base_convert](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) is a function which happens to do exactly what you want to do.

```
string base_convert ( string $number , int $frombase , int $tobase )
```

Its input structure is limited between base 2 and base 36 so it covers what you need. It is most likely (like many other PHP functions) just a light wrapper over the C library originals.

### GMP:

[gmp_strval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-strval.php) is another function which happens to do exactly what you want to do -- it also has better precision (because GMP is a multiprecision arithmetic library).

GMP values need to be initialized  from strings using `gmp_init` and the resulting value (is a resource) is used in all subsequent GMP arithmetic function calls.

It has a higher number of available bases (from 2 to 62) but it is a bit less fun to work with because of the requirement to init the values and use them as resources.

The less fun part isn't true if you're running PHP 5.6 because GMP overloads the arithmetic operators in that version allowing GMP objects (resources?) to be added substracted etc. by using the operators.

Here's a simple GMP conversion function example that doesn't require that you initialize values with `gmp_init`:

```
function gmp_convert($num, $base_a, $base_b)
{
    return gmp_strval ( gmp_init($num, $base_a), $base_b );
}
```

Comment: PHP built in functionality always the best ;)

Comment: Limited because imagination and keyboards run out. But it usually is faster.

Comment: thanks a lot, but according to the official website: "base_convert() may lose precision on large numbers due to properties related to the internal "double" or "float" type used." Can you please explain what "large numbers" are?

Comment: they are like small ones, but there are more of them

Comment: @Luka Large as in 'larger than 31bits on a 32bit system, or larger than 63bits on a 64bit system'.

Comment: is there any way to get this work with 64 bit numbers in both 32 and 64 bit systems?

Comment: @Luka check out my updated answer. GMP will rock your world. Even though I don't know why you would need all of that precision.